# Visual studio code remote-ssh code syntax highlight

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vscode-remote-ssh

I'm remotely connecting via Microsoft remote-ssh plugin on Visual code studio 1.65.2 on Manjaro Linux (rolling build 64-bit). I'm having trouble with syntax highlight, it does not work. I work otherwise locally or via mapped drives, but not over remote ssh. Am I missing something, perhaps configuration? I would prefer not install to plugins on remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I think plugin was needed to be installed on the server to make this work, however I was trying to avid that. Instead I used the FTP plugin to sync the files between local folder and remote.